# How to add and remove class using media queries at a partucular width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I'm trying to add a class when the width is `576px` or less and remove that class when the width is greater than `576px`, but it's not working. What I'm doing wrong. Please help. I'm doing this in multiple files.

.php file:

```
<body>
    <h1 id="hello"> Hello </h1>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script>
        matchMedia("(max-width: 576px)").addListener(max_width_f);
        matchMedia("(min-width: 577px)").addListener(min_width_f);
    </script>
</body>
```

---

.js file:

```
var h = document.getElementById("hello");
function max_width_f() {
    h.classList.add("no-display");
}
function min_width_f() {
    h.classList.remove("no-display");
}
```

---

.css file:

```
.no-display{ display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works, but did you try to check the width of your h1-element inside of the script? This would be the way I would try it, but I´m not sure if this is the way to do it.

```
function max_width_f() {
    if(h.width < 576)
      h.classList.add("no-display");
}
function min_width_f() {
    if(h.width > 577)
      h.classList.remove("no-display");
}
```

Then you could simply call the function in a script tag.